# JUnit GUI doesn't show executed test methods

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I run a test class, the outprint in console is correct, but the list of the @Test methods doesn't appear in the JUnit tab:

[image: Test class executed]

How to fix it?
Does the asterisk of the icon of the tab of the JUnit indicate  any kind of problem (the same problem)?

Answer (score 3):

You are setting [show failures only](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/ref-view-junit.htm) (the red and blue Xs), click on it to show all JUnit runs

[image]

> Show Failures Only Shows only failed tests.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the "Show Failures Only" button:

[image]

[image]